# Raspberry pi RPi.GPIO module for executable files

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, pyinstaller, raspberry-pi2

I want to run a simple python program to glow LED. I want to run as executable file on my raspberry pi. my simple test.py code is

```
print"Welcome to LED program"
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(25,GPIO.OUTPUT)
GPIO.OUTPUT(25,True)
```

this program runs fine if i use

```
sudo python test.py
```

now i convert it into executable file

```
sudo pyinstaller test.py
```

and execute it by

```
sudo ./test
```

output gives
welcome to LED program. Import error: No module name RPi.GPIO.

I used the 1st print command to ensure that executable file conversion is correct and the program is executing correctly.

Now what happened to RPi.GPIO? why the module is not found in case of a executable file??

Answer (score 0):

Some Python scripts import modules in ways that PyInstaller cannot detect.

You can solve this with similar way to this:

```
sudo pyinstaller --onefile --paths=\your-path\Lib\site-packages  .\test.py
```

For [more detail](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/)